# Magic Functions in PHP and their use?

Tags: php

i have been reading about magic functions lately, and I'm really confused about their implementations. Some Magic functions such as `__contruct()` and `__destruct()` are very useful. Magic functions like `__construct()` could be used to initialize variables with default values.

However I'm really confused with the implementation of other magic functions such as `__isset(), __call(), __toString(), etc`. What is the actual purpose of implementing the Magic Functions.

Yes, I do understand they are invoked behind the scenes and do not require a function call, but then what is their main advantage in real world, in terms of security-sql injection-scope. The main difference between `isset()` and `__isset()` (or any other Magic Function) and the situations in which I should use them?

Comment: Well look at [magic methods](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php)

Comment: `__toString()` is when you do `echo $class` https://repl.it/Cd6w/1

Comment: @bub Yes I did and I still don't find its use in real world. Can you please explain instead of posting links? Some examples and explanation would be good.

Comment: Class Method !== Function

Comment: No, I am not here to explain things to you where you can easily find tons of tutorials

Comment: Well none of the above comments answer my question, i need to know their actual purpose in real world scenario. Their scope and using them in terms of security. Anyway thank you.

Comment: This question doesn't really fit the SO format which is why you're not getting hugely helpful responses I'm afraid... Class Methods (e.g. `__isset()`) and PHP functions (e.g. `isset()`) are scoped completely differently; what you need is an OOP PHP tutorial **not** an SO *"quickfix"* answer.

Comment: Bummer!!! I was hoping to modify the default behavior of some of the magic functions. Maybe add some additional code to sanitize variables and return variables or objects or other possible values.

Comment: That's precisely what you do - for instance, you can add a `__get($var)` magic method to your class. That can retrieve, sanitise and return the relevant data from the class member (private or otherwise).

Comment: @CD001 Umm.. I really didn't wanted a quick-fix. But I was hoping for a better understanding on the topic to use them in a better way in future. Anyway, thanks for the response :)

Comment: In a nutshell: it allows you simplify syntax in certain circumstances. That's pretty much all. E.g. it allows you to write `$myObj->foo` instead of `$myObj->getFoo()` while still retaining the possibilities of a function call. If you extend "magic methods" to include `ArrayAccess` and `Iterable` it allows you some polymorphic possibilities like `$myObj['foo']` and `foreach ($myObj as ...)`.

Answer (score 6):

You shouldn't use magic methods in PHP unless you want some documented magic functionality.

They allow you to react to certain events when using these particular objects. This means when certain things happen to your object, you can define how it should react in that instance.

Each of these methods are triggered automatically and you are just defining what should happen under these circumstances.

Probably you won't ever need to use any of them besides `__construct()` and `__destruct()` when dealing with objects.

`__construct()` - Is called when an object is first created. You can inject parameters and dependencies to set your object up.

`__destruct()` - Is called when an object is destroyed. You can write some cleanup code here. Closing any open datastreams, database connections... whatever.

`__get()` - Listens for get requests of the properties.

`__set()` - Listens for set requests of the properties.

`__isset()` - Triggered by calling isset() or empty() on the object's properties.

`__unset()` - Triggered by calling unset() on the object's properties.

`__toString()` - Allows you to define how an object will behave when it's treated like a string.

`__sleep()` - Code defined here will run before you use serialize(). So you can define which properties of the object should be serialised.

`__wakeup()` - This is used to reinitialize any tasks that may have been put to stop during the serialization.

`__invoke()` - Defines how your class should behave if you "invoke" it and use it like a function.

`__clone()` - Triggered when cloning an object is finished. (If you copy your objects they are still linked to their original as they are still referencing it. Cloning can get you a clean copy.)

`__debugInfo` - Triggered when using var_dump() on the object. You can use it to control what kind of info should show up in the dump. If the method isn't defined on an object, then all public, protected and private properties will be shown.

Comment: So suppose for example, isset() is used to check if a variable/object exist. If i write my own __isset(), would i be able to change the default behavior of isset()??

Comment: kinda like operator overloading in C++??

Comment: Yes. __isset() captures the result of isset() and you can manipulate the output as you see fit.